# Why is my Bootstrap modal not working on my button?

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, modalpopup

I am using sublime text for my coding. I am working on a website contact page submission. I would like the button to be part of the contact page form.

Submit

```
<div class="modal" id="submitModal" tabindex="-1" >
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"  dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h2 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"> 
        <p>Your submission was successful!</p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I would like the button to be responsive when clicked. However, it is responsive.

Comment: This is my button trigger code......<!--button trigger-->
  <div class="col-lg-8 align-self-baseline">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-target="#submitModal" data-toggle="modal">
  Submit</button>